# How to flatten the packages in Eclipse with pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using the Eclipse 4.9.0 with pydev installed on it. The pydev version is 7.0.3.201811082356

If I create a package called a.b.c in the Python project then Eclipse displays it hierarchically in the project explorer window. To see the Python modules under a.b.c you need to expand a, b, and then C. What I would like to see is flattened version i.e. a.b.c so I just click once to expand it and see all the modules under it. If any of you have developed Java in Eclipse you would know what I am talking about. In Java if you create a package called a.b.c then Eclipse will show it as a.b.c so you just expand it once to see all the classes under package a.b.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you're talking about, unfortunately, this feature is not available in the PyDev package explorer (I think only JDT actually has that feature).

So, unfortunately, right now, you have to expand the actual folders to see your structure (there's no flattened version available).